# Pre-populate rich text field in the case creation page

Tags: visual-workflow, case, inputrichtext

Here is what I am trying to do:

1. Pre-populate a custom field(rich text) on cases in the creation page
2. The total characters is about 5000 characters with formatting (bolding, underlining)
3. The size of the field at the case creation page shows at least 15 lines so all the text shows without having the manually change the size.

Here is what I have tried to do:

- Default Values: rich text fields do not support default values and
  only show 3 lines.
- Process Builders: only populate after case is created
- Flows: not sure if this is possible
- VisualForce: This is my last resort.

The actual text to be pre-populated:

> Inquiry submissions should include:
>
> **Background:** What is the initiative or priority which is driving the client's need to connect with an analyst?
>
> **Agenda:**  •Inquiry Sessions: describe 1-3 questions you'd like the Analyst to address.  •Guidance Sessions: describe what the client
> wants to accomplish during the call.
>
> **Additional Participants:**
>
> **Additional Internal Context:** success criteria, client read research, other details

Comment: did you try a before save Flow?

Comment: Any reason each of your bolded pieces couldn't just be its own custom field with its own help text? No doubt, I'm sure the request is as you laid it out, but I'd fight for simplifying it versus sticking everything in one big rich text field and having to go down the road of overriding the default create screen. Easier reporting, filtering, can add validation rules to require certain parts, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way to this other than vf page or apex. Both flows and PB's need to have a DML action to populate.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to prefill a Rich Text field using a Case Quick Action.  I put the text to prefill in a custom label as html.  Used `<ul><li></li></ul>` to get bullet points, `<br>` for line breaks.  In a the Quick Action 'New Note' I used the predefined field values section to set the parent case id field to Case.id.  I set the rich text field to $Label.myOutline (custom label name).  Add the Quick Action 'New Note' to the Case Highlights Panel. When clicked it will display a New record form with the fields prefilled.  Haven't found a way to do this at the related list level.